# Removing instance of line only after first instance has occurred when writing a new file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text, streamwriter

Sorry for my terrible topic title but I couldn't think of another way to define it...
I am reading a text file and then missing out particular lines and then writing the lines I want to keep to a new file... I want to keep the column header which are default in the file but they occur multiple times down the page - and I only want them once at the top, I need some help with what I will need to put in my code to remove all the instances of the headers after the first has been read... here is my code so far which works fine what I want - to give you some context...

```
            string line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string lineDelete = "";
            string lineData = "#";
            string copy = "rcpy"; 
            string cp = "vvcp";
            string dash ="-------";
           string total = "total";

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test3.txt"))
                {
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line = line.Trim();

                        if (line.Contains(lineData))

                            continue;

                        if (line.Contains(copy))
                            continue;

                        if (line.Contains(cp))
                            continue;

                        if (line.Contains(dash))
                            continue;

                        if (line.Contains(total))
                            continue;

                        else
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Please include a sample input file along with your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder instance to form your result (to add the line at the beginning you should use Insert method with first parameter set to 0 and second line to add:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tyt41s0(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tyt41s0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

If the header may appear in file few times there is possibility to keep track whether you've added it already with bool vraiable.

After you've formed your result you can save it to file:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test3.txt"))
{
    outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Will try this logic soon